# python assign list to tk stringvar

Tags: python, list, tkinter

I'm having some trouble with stringVars from TK.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
strVar = StringVar()
tmp1 = ['one','two','three']
print(tmp1)
print(len(tmp1))

strVar.set(tmp1)
tmp2=strVar.get()
print(tmp2)
print(len(tmp2))
```

Output is:

```
['one', 'two', 'three'] 
3
('one', 'two', 'three')
23
```

As you can see, the format is different. Obviously, the list of strings is internally converted into one string with quotes. What ist the reason and how can I avoid it? For my script I would like to have a list of strings for further processing.

Comment: While the idea to assign a list to a string var is funny, that's actually not a bad question, What _is_ going on there? Why is the list first converted to tuple and then to string? E.g. if you pass a number or a dict to the string var, those are converted to str _only_.

Comment: Why do you feel like you need to keep your list of strings in a `StringVar`? What's wrong with using just a normal  python list?

Comment: A better idea might be to just have the user enter a number of strings separated by some special character (space, comma, semicolon, whatever), and then `str.split` the value of `strVar.get()` accordingly. That's even easier to use than having to enter all those `[`, `'`, etc.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your replies, I have to admit that I am pretty new to python and especially to TK. Background is that I get a list of strings from a system command like 
result = subprocess.run(['...']).stdout.decode('ascii')
which I pass to a listbox via StringVar. At a later point I want to get the data back from this StringVar to use it further.

Comment: @Jensenmann: you don't need to use a `StringVar` to move data in and out of a listbox.

Comment: Thanks Bryan, I will check that again. My observation was that Listbox is not updated when a variable is set which is not one of the TK classes. Any other (python) variable assigned to "listvariable" will not update the content, because it's not tracked http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm

Answer (score 1):

@tjt263, it's very long time ago, but I think I solved it like

```
    fdupesSV.set(fdupesList)
    tmp = subprocess.run(['fdupes', '-r',directory.get()], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

    #first convert bytes to ascii, then split at '\n', then assign so fdupesOut
    fdupesList=tmp.stdout.decode('ascii').split('\n')
    fdupesSV.set(fdupesList)
```

I am not sure if I remember the issue correctly but I hope it helps you

Cheers 
Jens

Answer (score 0):

```
from tkinter import *
import ast

root = Tk()
strVar = StringVar()
tmp1 = ['one','two','three']
print(type(tmp1), tmp1, len(tmp1))

strVar.set(tmp1)
x = ast.literal_eval('[' + strVar.get()[1:-1] + ']')
print(type(x), x, len(x))
```

Comment: Hi thanks for the post. Even if this works, it seems to me not very clean. Background is that I get a list of strings from a system command like 
_result = subprocess.run(['...']).stdout.decode('ascii')_ 
which I pass to a listbox via StringVar. I learned now that StringVar is not designed to hold any lists, so I think I should rather keep the list in a separate python list variable and just convert the list to string before setting the stringvar for the listbox.

Comment: @Jensenmann, Hi, that's exactly what I'm trying to do. Did you find a good solution?

Comment: @tjt263, please find my answer above

Answer (score 0):

I've just tested an easy way to do this, which was suggested by tobias_k's comment above

Start with your list of strings, but rather than encoding them, just join the list of strings into a single string using newline or another separator (if your strings might include newline).

Then just split the strings after getting the value.

For example:

```
# To set the string variable:

list_of_strings = ['Str 1', 'Str 2', 'Str 3']  # your data

list_var = tk.StringVar()
list_var.set('\n'.join(list_of_strings)

# To read the string variable:
received_list = list_var.get().split('\n')
```

if your initial list of strings includes newlines, then you could use any other character to join the strings.